# Convolutional neural network for gray images

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, computer-vision, convolutional-neural-network

I am using vgg16 to design a CNN that takes gray input images. The model give me good results without changing anything **related to colors**.

I am not sure if what I did is correct or not. I want to know should I change the model to be suitable for gray images?
Is what I did is correct?